# Epiphany: Change user-agent

Tags: epiphany

on arch-site i found this (gnome-web):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ user-agent 'Bunnies! Lots of bunnies in my user agent!'
```

but when i run it on terminal it does not work.
prompts out: `"scema is not movable (path must not be given)"`

so i tried it without the path:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany.web user-agent 'Bunnies! Lots of bunnies in my user agent!'
```

and now it says:

```
no such key <user-agent>
```

so anybody there with a suggestion to fix that?
Would be grate! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you found for Arch are correct for modern versions of Epiphany, but Loki ships with Epiphany 3.18, which is old. Removing the path was good, but the schema ID also changed slightly. I think this should work:

`gsettings set org.gnome.Epiphany user-agent 'Bunnies! Lots of bunnies in my user agent!'`